# Java: what happens when an already loaded class is deserialized

Tags: java, classloader

Let's say class `com.Foo` is loaded from a JAR and later a class with the same name `com.Foo`, but different definition (other fields) is deserialized (e.g loaded either from DB, or received from a remote call).

What could be the consequences? Will the new received class have any impact? Let's say that the class is used in other parts of the application, being persisted in DB and serialized/JSON encoded later.

Comment: Do they have a serial? Becuse if it is different there will be an exception. Otherwise you'll get an other exception stating the difference between the fields.

Comment: You typically don't deserialize a class (as in `com.Foo.class`), you deserialize objects of a class. And deserializing objects of `com.Foo` requires that the correct `com.Foo` class is already loaded so that this class can load objects according to it's definition. You'll run into trouble if the loaded class does not know how to interpret the data.

Comment: Classes are not serialized or deserialized ! Its the objects.

Comment: @AdamArold yes, the class implements Serializable (meaning the instances of the class are serializable, not the class itself, which is anyway Serializable).

Comment: @zapl Yes, typically you do not serialize classes, but rather *instances* of that classes, but suppose you receive one (it is easy to imagine such an attack).

Comment: Suppose you do? What kind of code are you envisaging that can succumb to this attack? `Class<X> cl = (Class<T>)oin.readObject();`? Are you really going to write this code? and what makes you think it's going to have any impact on the already loaded class? How exactly could it do that?

Comment: @AmanArora typically they are not serialized, but you *can* serialize also classes, as they implement the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: @EJP you are asking me my question :) As an example of decoding such a class: with JPA.

Comment: The answer to all the questions I asked is that you can't, and it can't.

Comment: `Let's say class com.Foo is loaded from a JAR and later a class with the same name com.Foo, but different definition (other fields) is deserialized`.How come you are having two classes with the same name?

Comment: @AmanArora What makes you think that the name is never serialized?

Comment: @AndreiI My question is how can you have two classes with the same name and both loaded in the JVM at the same time?How is this scenario possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deserialize a `Class<?>` object then the class with the fully-qualified class name gets loaded. If it is already loaded you will get the reference to that class.

I think that for a complete answer you should read [Java Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html)

Here are some quotations from the spec that I think are interessting:

*1.1 Overview*

> Special handling is required for arrays, enum constants, and objects of type Class, ObjectStreamClass, and String. Other objects must implement either the Serializable or the Externalizable interface to be saved in or restored from a stream.

*2. Object Output Classes*

> If the object is a Class, the corresponding ObjectStreamClass is written to the stream, a handle is assigned for the class, and writeObject returns.

*3. Object Input Classes*

> If the object in the stream is a Class, read its ObjectStreamClass descriptor, add it and its handle to the set of known objects, and return the corresponding Class object.

Comment: +1 For the link (a link to the documentation is always welcome)

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong imagination of how `Serialization` works. You can write a `Class` instance to an object stream just like other objects but this will *not* write the byte code of that class nor its definition to the stream. It just creates a symbolic reference to the class which is resolved like any other class reference of the stream: by using its symbolic name trying to resolve it in the context of the class deserializing it. It does not create a new class.

In fact, an instance of `java.lang.Class` creates even less dependencies to the actual class than writing an instance of it. The instance depends on the serialized form, e.g. the non-`transient` field of the class, while the symbolic reference represented by an instance of `java.lang.Class` does not depend on it.

The compatibility between the class present when writing a stream and the class present when deserializing it is determined by the `serialVersionUID` if it doesn’t match, deserialization will always fail with an exception. If it matches, the implementation will try its best to recover. Fields not present in the stream get their default values, stream fields not present in the actual class and any other unprocessed extra data will be ignored.

Comment: I will reformulate it: In the last paragraph: are you talking about deserialization of an instance of a class `com.Foo`?

Comment: If you (de)serialize an instance of `java.lang.Class` the class represented by it even doesn’t need to be serializable. It’s nothing more than a name then. For serializable classes the `serialVersionUID` will be stored and must match with the id of the actual class when deserializing. If it matches, the verification succeeds, regardless of how the instances look like in the stream. The description of how fields are matched applies to the instance of classes *other then* `Class`, `String` or `enum`s.